# Implement an excel pivot table in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pivot-table, xlwings

I've trying for days to implement a pivot table on my mac os with different libraries and ended up using xlwings as it looks like it supports it. I mostly see examples on windows but not mac. After some research I ended up with the code below but it crashes ont this line `pivot_table = pivot_sheet.api.create_pivot_table(table_destination=pivot_range.api, read_data=data_range.api, table_name='MyPivotTable')`. I'm a newbie at this so I might be doing it wrong or using a wrong syntax for mac. Bellow also is the error I'm getting.

I could have used pandas but it doesn't really look like a pivot table when saved to an excel file. I need one that will let me add the rows, columns, filter, and value fields.

This [github file](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/main/resources/mac/mac_dict_1642.py) I found has mac os syntax which is different from windows

Any help will be appreciated

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import constants

# Open the workbook
wb = xw.Book('test_excel.xlsx')

# Select the data range
data_range = wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1:C6')

# Create the pivot table
pivot_sheet = wb.sheets.add(name='PivotT')
pivot_range = pivot_sheet.range('A1')

print(pivot_range.api)
print(data_range.api)
pivot_table = pivot_sheet.api.create_pivot_table(table_destination=pivot_range.api, read_data=data_range.api, table_name='MyPivotTable')

# Add the fields

# structure the pivot table
pivot_table.pivot_fields('Name').orientation = constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
pivot_table.pivot_fields('Gender').orientation = constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField
pivot_table.pivot_fields('Age').orientation = constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField

DataField = pivot_table.add_data_field(pivot_table.pivot_fields('Age'))
DataField.Function = constants.TotalsCalculation.xlTotalsCalculationSum

# Save and close the workbook
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/pivot table/pt_code.py", line 257, in <module>
    pivot_table = pivot_sheet.api.create_pivot_table(table_destination=pivot_range.api, read_data=data_range.api, table_name='MyPivotTable')
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/pt_python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 515, in __call__
    raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
appscript.reference.CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -50
        MESSAGE: Parameter error.
        COMMAND: app(pid=9891).workbooks['test_excel.xlsx'].worksheets['PivotT'].create_pivot_table(table_destination=app(pid=9891).workbooks['test_excel.xlsx'].worksheets['PivotT'].cells['A1'], read_data=app(pid=9891).workbooks['test_excel.xlsx'].worksheets['Sheet1'].cells['A1:C6'], table_name='MyPivotTable')
```

**TEST CODE**

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('test_pt.xlsx')
app = wb.app
try:
    app.Run('') # not sure of what to put here
    print("here")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
wb.save()
```

**.bas File**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$P$30"), , xlYes).Name = _

        "Table1"

    Range("Table1[#All]").Select

    Sheets.Add

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _

        "Table1", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", _

        TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=8

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    Cells(3, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("market")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("wallet")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("period")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("device")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("device_model")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("device_manufacturer")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("card prov")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("instant_acc")

        .Orientation = xlPageField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Attemps")

        .Orientation = xlRowField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("in check")

        .Orientation = xlRowField

        .Position = 2

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("flow")

        .Orientation = xlRowField

        .Position = 3

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("event reason")

        .Orientation = xlRowField

        .Position = 4

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("status")

        .Orientation = xlColumnField

        .Position = 1

    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("nconv"), "Sum of nconv", xlSum

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can do it in VBA then highly likely that you can do the same in Xlwings, **on Windows**. Mac generally should be the same but it is known that Apple change things that stop the expected functions from working (and there may not be a work around). Do you have the ability to try this on a Windows setup?

Comment: @moken, thank you for replying. I'll have to try it on a virtual machine as I don't have access to a windows machine. One other thing, is there a way to let say write the script, save it to a VBA .bas file and execute that file within a python script to make the pivot table? This could be another way but I'm not sure if it will work or how to go about it

Comment: "write the script, save it to a VBA .bas" The script would have to be VBA which can only be run by an MS Office app, in this case Excel. You could certainly use VBA as the language that creates the pivot table and then use Python/Xlwings to run that script/macro. Even have Python pass arguments to the macro in order for it to be more dynamic. Being that the pivot table creation would be done by VBA that should avoid any issues between platform OS but you'd need to learn some VBA if your not familiar. Its not terribly difficult and there will be plenty of examples online to help.

Comment: @moken So I updated the original post and added my `.bas` and python file but I can't make it to work. The `.bas' was generated but on a macro I recorded for a test excel data I had. I trimmed it down to the important stuff. I tried writing a python code to make it work but it's not working as intended. The code only opens the excel file with my data and does nothing else. Can you help me with this? I don't have so much knowledge in this so i might be going about this all wrong